# Regex for specific forum

Tags: regex

I don't really know how to use regex, and I have a task to get bulk image downloader to find a set amount of pages for example pages 1-20 to link crawl.

This is the URL:

```
/index.php?app=core&module=search&do=viewNewContent&period=month&userMode=&search_app=forums&sid=ceb2a9ba4039e4a06d3a6775aa735f2d&search_app_filters[forums][searchInKey]=&st=400
```

Its page (the `st` param) is incremented in +25 so the following page would be:

```
/index.php?app=core&module=search&do=viewNewContent&period=month&userMode=&search_app=forums&sid=ceb2a9ba4039e4a06d3a6775aa735f2d&search_app_filters[forums][searchInKey]=&st=425
```

How can I match and replace the page number with the next consecutive page number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just capture the last digits and use whatever language you're writing in to increment that by 25:

```
/(\/index\.php.+?)(\d+)$/
```

This will give you the URL in $1 and the page number in $2 or matches[2] (however your language of choice represents the first "capture").  With that, you can increment it.

This Ruby example will do that:

```
matches = url.match(/(\/index\.php.+?)(\d+)$/)
page = matches[2].to_i               # Convert the page number to integer
page = page + 25                     # Calculate the new page number
new_url = matches[1] + (page).to_s   # Merge in the new page number
```

That should do it for this format of URL.